# My windows batch says: "72 was unexpected at this time."

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My batch file below, creates an .avs file for given list of parameters and then runs a program which takes this .avs file as an argument and does this multiple times in a for loop.

But when I run my batch file, it prints `72 is unexpected at this time.`, `72` is value of one of the parameters. The .avs file is not created and the program is not executed.

My batch file and its output on command prompt with `REM @echo off` is below.

My batch file:

```
REM @echo off

set RawSource26=C:\_rawsource26\RawSource26.dll
set avsFile=.\temporary.avs
set avs2yuv=C:\_avs2yuv\avs2yuv.exe

set video=balloons
set views=^
1 ^
2 ^
3 ^
4 ^
5
set rates=^
1Mbps ^
2Mbps ^
3Mbps ^
4Mbps ^
5Mbps
set width=1024
set height=768
set cropLeft=72
set cropTop=0
set cropRight=0
set cropBottom=0

(for %%v in (%views%) do (
  @echo. 2> %avsFile%
  @echo LoadPlugin("%RawSource26%") >> %avsFile%
  @echo Crop(RawSource(".\renderOut\%video%_%%v_synth.yuv", %width%, %height%, "i420"), %cropLeft%, %cropTop%, %cropRight%, %cropBottom%) >> %avsFile%
  %avs2yuv% %avsFile% -raw -o .\avsOut\%video%_%%v_synth_avs.yuv
  (for %%r in (%rates%) do (
    @echo. 2> %avsFile%
    @echo LoadPlugin("%RawSource26%") >> %avsFile%
    @echo Crop(RawSource(".\renderOut\%video%_%%v_%%r_synth.yuv", %width%, %height%, "i420"), %cropLeft%, %cropTop%, %cropRight%, %cropBottom%) >> %avsFile%
    %avs2yuv% %avsFile% -raw -o .\avsOut\%video%_%%v_%%r_synth_avs.yuv
))))

REM del %avsFile%
```

My command prompt:

```
C:\SAFAS\folder02>avs.bat

C:\SAFAS\folder02>REM @echo off

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set RawSource26=C:\_rawsource26\RawSource26.dll

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set avsFile=.\temporary.avs

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set avs2yuv=C:\_avs2yuv\avs2yuv.exe

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set video=balloons

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set views=1 2 3 4 5

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set rates=1Mbps 2Mbps 3Mbps 4Mbps 5Mbps

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set width=1024

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set height=768

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set cropLeft=72

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set cropTop=0

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set cropRight=0

C:\SAFAS\folder02>set cropBottom=0
72 was unexpected at this time.
C:\SAFAS\folder02>  @echo Crop(RawSource(".\renderOut\balloons_%v_synth.yuv", 1024, 768, "i420"), 72, 0, 0, 0) >> .\temporary.avs
C:\SAFAS\folder02>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `)` within your loops that are not actually a "close" but part of the `echo`es need to be "escaped" - replace then with `^)` otherwise batch takes an unescaped-`)` as `close of block`

Comment: OK. It worked. Would escaping opening parentheses `^(`, which are not meant as an "open", be a good practice?

Comment: Escaping closing parentheses which are not meant as a part of command in my batch solved my problem. Also escaping opening parentheses which are not part of a command did not break anything and signified that they are not part of a command. I would say escaping opening parentheses is a good practice. Thanks.

Comment: Escaping opening parentheses like `^(` is not needed but does not harm either, so it is not a question of good or bad practice, it is more a matter of personal taste...